# Custom 404 page when deploying static sites with Ionos Deploy Now, and HUGO server system

Tags: github, github-actions, hugo, static-site, ionos

I've never worked with HUGO before, it is apparenantly some kind of static site hosting service, I am the owner of an Ionos domain, and I want to use their "Deploy Now" service, they allow you to host a website on github, and use Hugo to run it, I dont know how to set a custom 404 page, the site works fine, but the 404 is a horrible plaintext 404 page. How can I change this?

Any help at all would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your project have a 404.html template? If not, you can create one in the `layouts` directory, and it should get picked up by Hugo, at least locally.

There's some more info on Hugo's docs: https://gohugo.io/templates/404/

Not too familiar with Ionos, but looks like you might need a step of additional config to get this picked up: https://www.ionos.com/help/hosting/html-and-css/create-your-own-error-pages-linux-webhosting/

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much, I honestly didn't expect this to work, but your link to the Ionos webhosting support page was perfect! I've searched tirelessly and had no success, but you have done a great job. Thank you so much.

Comment: @rho that's great news! So glad to hear it worked